# Manual dependency Maven and Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have created a Job in Jenkins with some goals in Maven (clean verify compile).
But, when I run the Job has the error:

```css
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project NameProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project NameProject:x:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.5, org.primefaces.themes:sentinel-theme:jar:2.1.2: Could not find artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.5 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I have created manual dependency in Maven

```css
mvn install:install-file
   -Dfile=<path-to-file>
   -DgroupId=<group-id>
   -DartifactId=<artifact-id>
   -Dversion=<version>
   -Dpackaging=<packaging>
   -DgeneratePom=true
```

,but Jenkins doesn't know this dependency in the pom.
When I execute verify compile in Maven it's works!, But when I execute in Jenkins doesn't work.

Comment: Did you install it on the Jenkins server?

Comment: I have installed Jenkins in localhost to test! The same local Maven.

Comment: Same user, or different?

Comment: With the same user

Comment: You'll have to look at your Jenkins setup, then, and figure out how it's resolving the Maven repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install it into a local repository, you need to install it into the local repository that is used by the Jenkins Server,i.e. you need to start mvn install on the Jenkins server.

If you have a company Nexus server, it is probably better to install it there.

Answer (score 0):

I [have changed](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/) the default local repository Maven

```css
<localRepository>C:/Users/nameUser/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

My Maven diretory was in a another drive (E:/), when repository in (C:).